# Small question in a proposition involving Ergodicity

Tags: lp-spaces, ergodic-theory

**Ergodicity** -- A measure preserving transformation $T$ on the space $(X,  \mathcal{B} ,  \mu)$ is called ergodic iff $\forall  B  \in\mathcal{B}$ satisfying $T^{-1} B = B$ we have $\mu(B) = 0$ or 1.

Let $T$ be a measure preserving transformation of a space $(X,  \mathcal{B},  \mu )$. Then the following are equivalent:

1. $T$ is ergodic;
2. For all f $\in$ L$^{1}$ (X, $\mathcal{B}$, $\mu$) satisfying $f \circ T = f$ a.e. then $f$ is constant a.e.

The book I am reading says that **"we can replace $L^{1}$ in above proposition by measurable or $L^{2}$"**. Why is that true? Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Have you seen the proof of $1. \iff 2.$? If so, look at the proof, you should see that it doesn't matter whether $f $ belongs to $L^1$ or $L^2$. i.e the same proof applies.

Comment: @Zestylemonzi  I don't seem to know what  1. \iff 2. proof you are talking about. Are you trying to say that on a finite measure space L1 = L2?? Sorry I am gonna take analysis (measure theory) this year... so don't have that much knowledge on this topic

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your measure $\mu $ is a finite measure. Suppose $T$ is erodic. $f$ is measurable and $f\circ T=f$ a.e.. Then $g\circ f \circ T=g\circ f$ a.e. for any $g$ measurable. Take a sequence of bounded measurable functions  $g$ on $\mathbb R$ converging pointwise to the identity function and apply the $L^{1}$ case to each $g_n\circ f$ to see that $g_n\circ f$ is a constant for each $n$. Hence $f =\lim g_n\circ f$ is also almost surely constant.

Comment: Take $g_n(x)=x$ for $|x| \leq n$, $n$ for $x >n$ and $-n$ for $x <-n$.